# DevForce Ideablade 2010 isn't regenerating the tt file. Runtime error indicates possible version mismatch

Tags: .net, entity-framework, visual-studio, silverlight, devforce

I have a Silverlight application that was using DevForce IdeaBlade 2010 version 6.1.15.0. I upgraded this to the latest version, found that there were too many breaking changes to deal with at this time and settled on version 6.1.16.1 as my target version.  Although all of my references appear to be correct, I'm getting the following error at runtime:

Unable to locate type: System.Linq.IQueryable`1[[[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], mscorlib, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], (omitted), Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Core, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e. Check that the assembly holding this type is available in the bin/exe folder. Also check that both your assemblies and DevForce assemblies have the expected version number on both client and server.

This seems to imply that there may be a version mismatch which I can't seem to track down. I found suggestions to delete the tt file, make a fake change in the edmx model and resave. At this point the tt file is supposed to be regenerated, but it isn't.

Any suggestions?

Here's more info on my environment:

DevForce IdeaBlade 2010 version 6.1.16.1

Silverlight 5

.NET 4.0

Visual Studio 2013

Prism 2.0.1.0

Answer (score 0):

There were a few problems with the 6.1.16.1 release and we removed it from our download portal a few weeks ago.  So first thing to do is download 6.1.16 from our site and install it.

When you open your EDM in the designer, make sure the "DevForce Enabled" property in the Model Properties window is set to true.  Then save the file (no fake changes needed).  This should cause the .tt to be regenerated, along with your code.

Also check that all projects in your solution are using this DevForce version.

Once the DevForce version of your model is generated and everything rebuilt, you shouldn't see the type locator problem.

Comment: Hi Kim, Thanks for your response.  I've now downloaded the version you mentioned, but I noticed in the "Software Prerequisites Summary" of the Installation Guide that it is specifying Visual Studio 2010 and Silverlight 4 with the Toolkit. I'm wondering if I need to switch back to those technologies or will it also work with the technology stack I listed at the bottom of my question.

Comment: We need to retire that Installation Guide, as it's filled with outdated information.  The DevForce Resource Center, specifically the [Release Notes](http://drc.ideablade.com/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/release-notes), have the most current information.  Your technology stack is supported.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know. Unfortunately, it's still not working for me. I removed and re-added all references to IdeaBlade in all affected projects in the solution. I confirmed that all of them were pointing to version 6.1.16.0 and that all were set to "Copy Local = True". The tt file still doesn't regenerate and I still get the same runtime errors. Maybe I'm missing one of the references that should be there?

Comment: Your references (from your email) look fine.  Did you check that the "DevForce Enabled" property is set to true for the model?  By default it will be false.

Comment: The "DevForce Enabled" property is set to true. It looks like there are two separate issues that I thought were connected, but aren't. I tried disabling the obfuscation that Eazfuscator was doing and the runtime errors went away. I'll need to find another way to obfuscate that doesn't confuse IdeaBlade. Are there certain types of obfuscation that I should specifically avoid? In the meantime, however, a deleted tt file still does not get recreated.

Comment: I'm not sure what else could be causing the problem with the .tt.  Maybe take a look at the DevForce Resource Center info (http://drc.ideablade.com/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/model%2Dgenerate) to see if anything there stands out.

Comment: When you save the EDMX, do a "File | Save" from the menu instead of using the toolbar - that may work.  Regarding obfuscation, you should have better luck if you don't obfuscate the model assembly on both client and server.  See the sample called [Separate Model Projects](http://drc.ideablade.com/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/code-sample-separate-model-projects) for solution structure.